# query on ansible loops

Tags: loops, ansible

I have 4 node cluster:

- NODE A
- NODE B
- NODE C
- NODE D

and I have to create 10 volumes each on the nodes:

I am using with_sequence which creates 40 volumes, but how i do iterate through nodes.

like after every 10 volumes, node should increment from node a to node b then node c and node d

- NODE A: vol1, vol2 , vol3 .....vol10
- NODE B: vol11, vol12, ..........vol20
- NODE C: vol21....................vol30
- NODE D: vol31....................vol40

this is my playbook:

tasks:

```
- name: Create volume
  na_ontap_volume:
    state: present
    volume: {{item}}
    root_volume: volumeroot
    root_volume_security_style: mixed
    hostname: "{{ aiqumip }}"
    username: "{{ aiqumusername }}"
    password: "{{ aiqumpassword }}"
    node: ??
    https: false
    validate_certs: false
 with_sequence: start=1 end=40
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your nodes are in an array,

```
- name: Create volume

  na_ontap_volume:

    state: present

    volume: {{item}}

    root_volume: volumeroot

    root_volume_security_style: mixed

    hostname: "{{ aiqumip }}"

    username: "{{ aiqumusername }}"

    password: "{{ aiqumpassword }}"

    node: "{{ nodes[((item|int-1)//10)] }}"

    https: false

    validate_certs: false
 vars:
   nodes:
     - NODE A
     - NODE B
     - NODE C
     - NODE D

 with_sequence: start=1 end=40
```

Comment: appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

have one more query:

wrt to the above question
like after every 10 volumes, node should increment from node a to node b then node c and node d. 
like this

NODE A: vol1, vol2 , vol3 .....vol10

NODE B: vol11, vol12, ..........vol20

NODE C: vol21....................vol30

NODE D: vol31....................vol40

now i want to create 80 volumes, so after 40 volumes, from 41 to 80 it should be repeat from node A till node D

like Node A should have volume from 1 to 10 and 41 to 50

Node b should have volume from 11 to 20 and 51 to 60

Node c should have volume from 21 to 30 and 61 to 70

Node d should have volume from 31 to 40 and 71 to 80